# Executing Node JS code on PHP to get header of a URL

Tags: php, node.js

Is it possible to execute some node js code within PHP tags to get a header for a URL?

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {method: 'HEAD', host: 'stackoverflow.com', port: 80, path: '/'};
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  }
);
req.end();
```

This is my node js code, all I need to do is execute this on PHP, (fingers crossed) !!

Comment: It's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am looking to try something, but have no idea where to start!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

node.js in PHP tags kind of suggests that either:

- A PHP script outputs node.js code, a node.js server calls the PHP script and then eval()'s it somehow.
- Node.js is embedded in PHP

Both is technically possible, but if I had to make a wild guess it's probably not what you want to do. PHP and Node.js are both typically server-side languages and can do similar things. Why not try to solve this problem with PHP code?

Comment: Because, PHP code does not work for me, I am making a CURL request through PHP, which kind of gets filtered, I was hoping since Node JS is basically Javascript, that would solve my problem, it's only one HTTP request I have to make though.

Comment: I think your best course of action is to figure out why your PHP code doesn't work. Calling PHP from node.js is possible but it's only really for very specialized circumstances and probably quite hard to setup. Maybe ask a new stackoverflow question with your PHP code?

Comment: I did that, I have been struggling on this for almost a month, and have posted several questions in stackoverflow, nothing helps, as a last resort, I am trying to find alternatives to PHP

Comment: I understand, but let me tell you this super clear: this alternative is way worse. If you link me to your PHP question I might be able to help with it.

Comment: Also, a recent hint or discovery, I hope it's positive - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413668/hostname-in-dns-cache-was-stale-zapped

Comment: I answered a question to the last stackoverflow question. It seems like you are already pretty far taking the approach with CURL, your code looks good. The DNS error is probably not relevant to your problem.